# is it the same to do a port scan on the public and the private side of a wifi router

Tags: networking, router, internet

is it the same to do a port scan on the public and the private side of a wifi router?

I would say no but I am not sure.

If I do a ports scan on the private side of my router I should get open ports 53, 80, 443 (for example) and now I do the same from my phone connected on a mobile 3G/4G network with a good bandwidth. For security reason a good result would be to get no open ports if I have no web server on the private side.

Am I correct in my assumption?

Comment: for the record, with my SOHO NAT Router, or any i've had, DNS/port 53 is open on the private side, but not the public. Similarly port 80, even port 23. That's default/ And if I did a port scan from the internet and found any of those ports open / unexpectedly open, i'd be wanting to look into that 'cos things shouldn't be open to the public without my knowledge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, at least not in general, but there are a lot caveats. First off, note that these comments are in regards to a standard Home/SOHO-grade routers, not Enterprise kit.

It is a common best practice to restrict management services to the LAN, or if you need remote, to allow only the specific remote address that will be connecting. Most routers ship with management only available on the LAN interface.

DNS may be a little different. Depending on your router and its configuration (whether or not masquerading is configured, and whether the router is configured as DNS server for the LAN, or you have another server running forwarding), you may need to have an open port for DNS traffic on UDP\53. you generally have to perform this configuration yourself, so you should know if you need UDP\53 opened.

Another exception is of course if you are forwarding port 80 or 443 inbound to a webserver for public consumption.

Another potential exception is devices in the home that use UPNP to forward 80/443 to themselves. Playstation4's for instance automap a number of ports.

Comment: I think if the answer to "is it the same to do a port scan on the public and the private side of a wifi router?",  is "Yes, at least in general", then the answer is no, so he is correct there.

Comment: @barlop if the answer is "Yes, at least in general", that means that the vendor/isp of the router does not do a good job if, for ex, he lets port 80 open?

Comment: To both of you: so you agree with me that the outcome of the ports scan "should" be different?

Comment: @Frank What would you say of the enterprise kit: block all from the router, put a fw behind? not an SME?

Comment: @narb  you write "To both of you: so you agree with me that the outcome of the ports scan "should" be different? " <-- my experience has been with SOHO NAPT routers, and yeah.  I see port 53 open on the private side(ok, DNS is pretty important) , and as expected, not on the public side. In other situations like if a place has lots of routers then maybe only one will have a public facing side, or if there are many public IPs and a router doesn't do NAPT because there are many public IPs and no private iPs are necessary then maybe the ballgame is a bit different.

Comment: @narb, yes, for a NAT router, they should be different under normal circumstances. Enterprise routers don't have a dedicated WAN or LAN. they just have interfaces that you configure as you need. my Ubiquity ER-8 has 8 ports, of which I decided one would be WAN (it connects upstream to the ISP network) and one that should be LAN (that connects to my switches), so I had to decide where management is allowed and whether or not to use NAT. its a bit different than your off-the-shelf linksys.